# Identify items and convert row to column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to identify any other items produced by employees besides "shoe" for any given month. Using my codes, the entire row(s) are removed as long as the employee produces "shoe" at that month. Any help would be greatly appreciated!.

Her is the sample data:

```
create table tbl
(
  Employee  char,
  Month     varchar (6),
  Monday    varchar (6),
  Tuesday   varchar (6),
  Wednesday varchar (6),
);

insert into tbl values 
('A',       'May'  ,    'Shoe',   '',        'Cloth'),
('A',       'March',    'Belt',   'Cloth',   'Hat'),
('A',       'July',     'Belt',   '',        ''),
('B',       'April',    'Shoe',   ''  ,      'Hat'),
('A',       'June',      '',      ''  ,      'Mask'),
('B',       'May',      'Shoe',   ''  ,      ''),
('C',       'March',    'Hat',    '',        'Shoe');
```

Here is the codes I used:

```
    select * 
    from   tbl
   where Monday not in ('Shoe') 
   and Tuesday not in ('Shoe') 
  and Wednesday not in ('Shoe')
```

Here is the expected outcomes:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this a bit via a `CROSS APPLY` to `UNPIVOT` your data

**Example**

```
Select Employee
      ,Month
      ,B.*
 From  tbl A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Monday'   ,Monday   )
                     ,('Tuesday'  ,Tuesday  )
                     ,('Wednesday',Wednesday)
             ) B(Day,Item)
 Where Item not in ('Shoe','')
```

**Results**

[image]

---

**EDIT - Just Another Option**

If you want to UNPIVOT your data without Dynamic SQL or enumerating all the columns (if many or variable), you can use a bit of JSON

```
Select Employee
      ,Month
      ,Day = B.[Key]
      ,Item = B.Value
 From  tbl A
 Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] not in ('Employee','Month')
                  and Value not in ('Shoe','')
             ) B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Employee,Month,'Monday' AS "Day",Monday AS "Item" FROM tbl WHERE Monday NOT IN ('Shoe','')
UNION ALL
SELECT Employee,Month,'Tuesday' AS "Day",Tuesday AS "Item" FROM tbl WHERE Tuesday NOT IN ('Shoe','')
UNION ALL
SELECT Employee,Month,'Wednesday' AS "Day",Wednesday AS "Item" FROM tbl WHERE Wednesday NOT IN ('Shoe','')
```

Comment: Two items:  1) You're missing the FROM  and 2) UNION ALL is more performant than UNION in this case.   UNION ALL does not require a SORT and on a batch basis it is 32% vs 68% using UNION.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti you're right for both, I forgot FROM and make UNION as ALL. I made correction for other readers. Thx